# Cannot restore or recover ipod Classic 80gb

Tags: ipod

I have an ipod Classic 80gb.   It is currently stuck on the apple screen.  I am unable to recover or restore the ipod.  It is not recognized by windows as either a ipod or a mass storage device.   When I plug it into my PC nothing happens.

It just sits there with the apple logo on the screen.  None of the buttons respond with the exception of a reset.  (toggle hold switch -> hold center + menu for 6 seconds.)  A reset will cause the screen to go blank for a few seconds.

Nothing else I have found seems to work.

Let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: Can you hear the disk spinning?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to diagnose the problem with the diagnostic mode.

To enter the diagnostic mode, press the folowing key when the apple logo appears after a reset :

**iPod 1G, 2G et 3G, press the keys for 5 seconds :**

- "back"
- "next"
- "select"

**iPod 4G, 5G, mini et nano,  press the keys for 5 seconds :**

- "back"
- "select"

In the diagnotic mode, you can navigate in the menus with the back/next keys and launch a bunch of test.

Answer (score -1):

The hard disk has probably failed. If so, your options include:

1. Buy a new iPod
2. Buy a replacement hard drive on eBay (etc) and replace it.
3. Find a used iPod somewhere and swap parts to yours until it works.

Comment: If you buy a used iPod wouldn't you just sync that with your library, rather than swapping parts?